# Staggering a program's resource-heavy operations?

Tags: c#, multitasking

When writing or reading from a large file, many of the amateur programs I've used end up freezing, which is understandable considering the size of the file it's reading or writing. When moving a file in windows are unzipping a program, or something like that, the programs never freeze and you can move the window around or cancel the operation.

How is this done? Do they have intermittent pauses in the operations to allow for the calculation of a button press or window movement instead of adding it to the end of the large operation? If so, how is this done?

Comment: One easy way is to use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) (the IO is done on *another thread* and watches for the "cancel" flag or other control-state) while the UI *always* happens on the thread of the window message-pump. Of course this same task can be done using more primitive operations. There are also async-IO approaches, which may or may not actually use additional thraeds.

Comment: More generally the intermittent pauses you suggest are there in the form of resource scheduling: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29. Threading is just one method by which we can break down computer resource (CPU, Memory, etc) intensive tasks in our applications into schedule-able pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are good the program spawns multiple [threads of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29). One thread is put in charge of the [Windows message loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows) so resizes, repaints, redraws, minimize / maximize etc. are all handled in a visually pleasing manner *and* clicking the "cancel" button can interrupt the *other* threads of control that manage compute-intensive or IO-intensive operations.